# react native tab navigator transparent background

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I build a custom tab navigation all works fine, my problem is I want to use a background video for all my pages, to prevent it from loading on every page new, I was thinking to just put the video in the root app.tsx where I placed my navigationContainer but it seems that something from the react-navigation adds a white background.

```js
   <NavigationContainer>
      <BackgroundVideo/>
      <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} tabBar={(props) => <BottomMenu {...props} />} >
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Tab.Screen name="About" component={About} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Contact" component={Contact} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
   </NavigationContainer>
```

if I set my BackgroundVideo to position absolute it doesn't show the video at all, I just get white screen and if I do not set position absolute I see the video and menu, but no page content from any of the Tab.Screen's.

placing the background video onto each page works, but it reloads every page change and I don't like that.

Anyone knows a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs some react hacks to fulfil the requirement.

Checkout the below code snippet, in which I have **created an high order component** and wrapped the bottom tabbar with it, which **will rendered only once**.

```
import React from 'react';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

const FirstScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text>{'First Screen'}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const SecondScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text>{'Second Screen'}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const BottomTab = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent', // made header transparent
        },
        tabBarStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent', // made bottom tabbar transparent
        },
      }}
      sceneContainerStyle={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent', // made screen transparent
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen name="first" component={FirstScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="second" component={SecondScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const withVideo = (WrappedComponent: any) => {
  return (props: any) => {
    // render background video player here by wrapping child..
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
        <WrappedComponent {...props} />
      </View>
    );
  };
};

const NewBottomTab = withVideo(BottomTab);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <NewBottomTab />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Not tested, I already found another solution ditching react navigation. so many errors and problems, now I use just a react component to render my page inside the menu

Comment: Okay, But I have tested and then I put this solution here. If you need in future you can try this.